# jsPDF muliple pages with div height - unable to determine the height

Tags: angularjs, jspdf

I am trying to generate a pdf from html divs with dynamic height and width. Below is the code.

```
let pages = this.rootDataContainer.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('pdfpage');

  for (let i = 0; i < pages.length; i++) { 
            this.pdfDoc.addHTML(pages[i], 0, 0, options, () => {
                let pxHeight = pages[i].offsetHeight / scaleFactor; 
                this.pdfDoc.addPage(0, pxHeight);
                this.counter = this.counter - 1;
            });
        }
```

There are couple of issues I am facing.

1. As addHTML is async, pages are added to pdf in random way.
2. height of the pdf page is either getting more or less height.

is there any way to set pdf size and sync the order of pages.

Answer (score 2):

To sync I would use a recursive approach as in:

**EDITED**:

```
var pages = document.getElementsByClassName("pdfpage");
var pdfDoc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [0, 0]);
pdfDoc.deletePage(1);
pdfDoc.addPage(pages[0].clientWidth, pages[0].clientHeight);

var addDivToPdf = function(pageNr) {
  pdfDoc.addHTML(pages[pageNr], 0, 0, {background:"#FFF"}, () => {
    if (++pageNr < pages.length) {
      //New added DIV dimensions here
      pdfDoc.addPage(pages[pageNr].clientWidth, pages[pageNr].clientHeight);
      addDivToPdf(pageNr);
    } else {
      pdfDoc.save("sample-file.pdf");
    }
  });
};
```

Notice I haven't use a for loop. This way the next page is added only when the previous is complete.

For the height, I'm not sure, scaleFactor must have the wrong units. It is not really clear if you want all pages to have the same size or you want different sizes to match the DIV height.

**UPDATE**: To control the widht and height according with the DIVs sizes, I have indicated 'pt' in the pdfDoc constructor:

```
var pdfDoc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [0, 0]);
```

However the first page appears to have always an standard size, so I have deleted it and added again with the desired size before adding the first DIV. The other pages can follow the normal flow:

```
pdfDoc.deletePage(1);
pdfDoc.addPage(pages[0].clientWidth, pages[0].clientHeight);
```

The CodePen is updated:
https://codepen.io/zameb/pen/BdbEVr

Comment: this code solves my page sync issue but unable to fix height.. :( .                        if my div size is 100px width and 100px height, I want same height in PDF also.

Comment: Some edits were applied, check if it fits your needs

Comment: seems var pdfDoc = new jsPDF('p', 'pt', [0, 0]);  & pages[0].clientHeight   this is helping to get height .. but not the width. .. :(

Comment: @Aswartha, it is not any kind to take time from others, not put interest in explain what exactly you need, not looking on how to set the width on a div (different to a height) and finally not even give some reps on responses. What you initially asked for is completely solved. But I even did a little more effort to adjust the div's width (very basic) to reflect it on the PDF: clientWidth is "actual size", it doesn't matter what you put on the css

Comment: sorry, my intention was not to take your time. as I said, the height was giving some problem..  but thanks for your time. I have set height also looks like everthing is working for me.